# Usage of StartsWith and Contains in List<string>?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list.

It's possible members (x123, y123, z123, a123, b123, c123).//123 is example
This "mylist" may contain a member that starting with x, or may not. Also this is the same for y,z,a,b,c.

```
If contains a member starts with x:
//Formula Contains X

If Not Contains a member starts with x:
//Formula Not Contains X

//same as all of x,y,z,a,b,c. But unlike a foreach, I must place the formulas at checking time, not after.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: it would not be a problem,the important thing is job, i can use.

Comment: Ok. I posted an answer for contains and not contains

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Checks if any items start with 'x' in your list:

```
bool result = mylist.Any(o => o.StartsWith("x"))
```

Checks if no items start with 'x' your list:

```
bool result = !mylist.Any(o => o.StartsWith("x"));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.Any` from `Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)

```
bool result = mylist.Any(o => o.StartsWith("x"));
```

This will iterate on the list and tell you if there is at least one element that starts with "x"

Comment: In this solution where must I place myList?

Answer (score 4):

```
public void Process(List<string> list, string key)
{
    if (list.Any(i => i.StartsWith(key)))
    {
        //Formula Contains key
    }
    else
    {
        //Formula Not Contains key
    }
}
```

then you can call

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "x123", "y123", "z123", "a123", "b123", "c123"};
Process(list, "x");
Process(list, "a");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> formula = new List<string> { "x123", "y123" };
string variable = "x";
bool containsVariable = formula.Any(s => s.StartsWith(variable));
```